Is it possible to connect a Drupal website to a non- Drupal web service?
I am a Drupal newbie. I wish to use Drupal to develop a website, but I need to be able to:

have Drupal navigation links and forms access a REST API served by a Quarkus- based service

interface with a React or Angular- based SPA


Is it possible for a Drupal site to work with non- Drupal apps and services? If it is, how would one do this?

SImple answer is yes,  but your question is way too vague to give any meaningful instructions on how to do it.
